# Puppet exec command with variable not executed

Tags: puppet, git, vagrant

I have a very simple Puppet (sub)module that should use Git to clone a repository from a remote location:

```
class wppuppet::git(
  $location = '/var/www/wp'
) {

  file { $location:
    ensure => 'directory',
    mode   => '0755',
  }

  exec { 'git-wp':
    command => 'git clone https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress ${location}',
    require => Package['git'],
  }

  Package['git']
  -> File[ $location ]
  -> Exec['git-wp']
}
```

For some reason it constantly fails with the following error:

```
Error: git clone https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress ${location} returned 128 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Wppuppet::Git/Exec[git-wp]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: 
git clone https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress ${location} returned 128 instead one of [0]
```

I tried it with `${location}` as well as with `$location`, but the result stays the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first problem is that you have your `command` parameter surrounded with single quotes (`'`), which inhibit variable expansion.  If you have:

```
$location = "/path/to/target"
```

Then:

```
file { '$location':
  ensure => directory,
}
```

Will attempt to create a directory called "`$location`", whereas this:

```
file { "$location":
  ensure => directory,
}
```

Would actually try to create `/path/to/target`.

With that in mind, your `exec` resource should probably look like:

```
exec { 'git-wp':
  command => "git clone https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress ${location}",
  require => Package['git'],
}
```

Also, it's not necessary to pre-create the target directory; `git` will do this for you.

You can run puppet with `--debug` in order to see the actual error messages output by `git`.